# HTML - Using pattern attribute

Tags: regex, html

In html form, I need textarea which allows any type of text: numbers, symbols, newline or letters, including Hebrew letters. The only two rules:

1. The input must include the string: "{ser}"
2. The input should prohibit any use of "{" or "}" except for the above string

I tried this:

```html
<form action="#">
...
  <textarea pattern="[^\{\}]*\{ser\}[^\{\}]*" required>
האם אתה נמצא בשבת הקרובה? אם כן נא השב {ser} + שם מלא
  </textarea>
...
  <input type="submit" />
...
                    </form>
```

But for some reason it also allows sending texts that do not meet the rules. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You have `patten`, not `pattern`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `pattern` attribute on textareas, see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea).

> maxlength specifies a maximum number of characters that the 
>   is allowed to contain. You can also set a minimum length that is
>   considered valid using the minlength attribute, and specify that the
>    will not submit (and is invalid) if it is empty, using the
>   required attribute. This provides the  with simple
>   validation, which is more basic than the other form elements (**for
>   example, you can't provide specific regexs to validate the value
>   against using the pattern attribute, like you can with the input
>   element**).

Perhaps implement a regex match with javascript?

```
function validateTextarea(text) {
  var re = /ser/g;
  var result = text.match(re);
  if(result != null && result.length > 0)
    // Do something
}
```

Then probably the best way is to check the function in `onsubmit` form attribute.